# Designing an optimal artifact release history json

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, jsonschema

I have many artifact releases, which can have artifact name, publication (optional) and version . So one artifact is uniquely determined by the three attributes. So let's say artifact A1, publication P1 and version v1 has a set of attributes which differ from artifact A1, publication P1 and version v2.

How can I model these as a JSON that can be consumed (both read and inserted into) on the server side.

I tried the following.

```
[
  {
  "ArticleName" : "Article one.",
  "ArticleImage" : "http://article.akamai.com/Support/images/1.jpg",
  "ArticleDetails": [ {
      "publication" : "",
      "version" : "v1",
      "title" : "Article version v1",
      "articleSize" : "532kb",
      "ArticleDownloadLink" : "",
      "ArticleFeatures" : ["f1", "f2"]
    }
.... // more article data goes here.
]
```

It is a list of dictionaries with each article having publication and version details. However I am unable to find a way to map an article to a publication and publication to versions.

How can I represent that as a JSON

Comment: can you give more detail? are you using mongo, postgres, araganodb. Like what do you mean?

Comment: I will initially hardcode the JSON and then push it to CDN to be consumed later. I just need the structure if the JSON to define the relationship mentioned in the question.